# Javascript remove hours mins from NewDate

Tags: javascript, date

I'm doing

```
    const thisMonth = new Date().getDate()
```

and it returns

```
   "2018-01-11T14:00:00.000Z"
```

So the question is how to remove all

```
       T14:00:00.000Z
```

i tried to use slice but it doesnt work, would highly apprecaite your help, tried to do everything i can and searched the web to find answers, if this post is a dubplicate and has been asked already please refer me to that thread, i tried to search but didnt find anything

Comment: thisMonth should return a number?

Comment: That's not possible. Provide a [mcve] that produces that output

Comment: I thought it was meant to return the date, i think its pretty minimal, complete and verifiable. What else to include, its a simple question "how to remove that unnecessary data, i dont know what else can be added to that question

Comment: Certainly not possible to get that ISO string from `getDate()` which returns an integer. Also show what you tried with `slice()`. No reason you can't slice the string

Comment: Note that this will return the UTC date, which is likely to be different to the local date based on time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Date#getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) returns the day of the month, a number, but not the date.

You could take [`Date#toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) for getting an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant string and use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) for the wanted part.

```js
const date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

console.log(date);
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @Stas—Noting that this returns the UTC date, not local.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toISOString()` method to format the date and split the rest :

```
var d=new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can code it like below:

```
var monthNames = [
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        ];

var new_date = new Date();
var day = new_date.getDate();
var monthIndex = new_date.getMonth();
var year = new_date.getFullYear();
localTime =  year + "-" + monthNames[monthIndex] + "-" + day; 
console.log(localTime.valueOf()); //2018-Jan-11
```

or

```
localTime =  year + "-" + (monthIndex + 1)+"-" + day; 
console.log(localTime.valueOf()); //2018-1-11
```

Comment: What do you mean paid by character? Do you see anywhere on this answer limits? If you don’t need valueOf, just use it without it. The question was about displaying date as expected, anything else is optional for user who asked the question.